# Elasticsearch vs AWSOpenSearch vs amplify OpenSearc

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-amplify, opensearch

Does anyone have experience with all this search engines?

What are pros and cons?

Are they all the same in speed and features?

I have amplify project with product table of 400 000 records.

What is the best to use in this case?

Comment: Hi, there are bunch of blogs available on google which explain differece between ES and OS. Did you try to search on google ? There is blog written by Elastic itself and you can refer it [here](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/opensearch)

Comment: This post is old. I haven't found any specific comparisons. I have amplify project on aws and i need info about speed in both cases.

Comment: I think so you will not find any specific documentation which will give comparision because speed will be depnds on your usecase, how much data you have, hardware configuration and all.